# C++ refer at const pointer before declare it

Tags: c++

I'm creating a menu and this menu is treestructure, here there is the code

```
typedef struct itemMenu{
    uint8_t id;
    char item[15];
    struct itemMenu *next;
};

const itemMenu menu0[] PROGMEM =
{
{1, "item1", menu1},
{2, "item2", 0},
{3, "item3", 0},
{0, "\n", 0}};

const itemMenu menu1[] PROGMEM =
{
{1, "item1", 0},
{0, "\n", menu0}};
```

The submenu is linked to the main one, the index (first field) 0 means reference to the previus menu. When I compile it, there is an error because the reference at menu1 is not possible on the first array. Is it possible to announce the menu1 before the declaration?

Comment: Why the `typedef` with no identifier? You don't need `typedef` at all for this in C++ anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can put:

```
extern const itemMenu menu1[];
```

before the definition of `menu0`.

Please note that there are a number of other errors in the code, however.  In particular, with the code as written, this:

```
struct itemMenu *next;
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
const struct itemMenu *next;
```

or more simply:

```
const itemMenu *next;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but now I recivied this  error from the compiler menu.cpp.o:(.progmem+0x0): multiple definition of `menu1'

Comment: @Alfredo You are probably defining it in a header file. Make both `menu0` and `menu1` `extern` and define them in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your answer, but the code is only in a .h file and when I try to compile with 2 references at menu0 I got the error

Comment: @Alfredo Exactly. If you only keep the `extern` declaration in the `.h` file and put the actual definitions in a `.cpp` file, you can include the `.h` from multiple `.cpp` files without getting the multiple definition problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Alfredo You're welcome. Hope it works out!